# Difference between main.xml and activity_main.xml?

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android. In various tutorials, I came across the mention of main.xml residing at res.layout folder. I use the latest version of eclipse. But I couldn’t find main.xml; instead I found activity_main.xml. 
Are these two (main.xml and activity_main.xml) the same?

Also I couldn't find linear layout tag as tutorial says it should be a default tag present when one opens a new project. Rather I find relative layout. I think due to this, all my elements(buttons) are overlapping. Please suggest a way to fix this.

Comment: main.xml is not a magic name; it is just the arbitrary name of a layout, which is used by the program to describe how the presentation looks.  You might just as well have called it my_great_layout.xml.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference between both the files. They are just differ by name. So

```
If your file name is activity_main.xml use it like this in onCreate()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

else

```
If your file name is main.xml use it like this in onCreate()
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

If its not liner layout, you can change it like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Follow this tut for more clearification,
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-linearlayout-example/

Comment: Thanks. Having both main.xml (default) and activity_main.xml was the reason why R had a red underline (IDE: Netbeans) in the following statement: import Android.<my package name>.R;

Answer (score 1):

main.xml is just a layout file which your project contains to store xml layout...
it will be auto generated if you are using ecipse (and eclipse will fix its name like activity_youractivityname.xml)

try to learn step wise 
1>first to create android project

```
File->New->android application project
```

follow the steps and if you are successful the android project will be created.

2>once your project will be created you can find your all .xml files within `res/layout` folder from project explorer

3>now open any of the xml you want from it and you can experiment with it as you want...

Answer (score 0):

main.xml

This is a just layout file which is used to making user interface.

It is always **res->layout** structure from project explorer.

You can create using your name with name conversion standard and it will be further used in your java file.

When you create project that time by-default create one `java and xml` file.so don't worry.